# Flutter TextField align

Tags: dart, flutter, textstyle

I need to create a TextFormField with decorations - counterText and labelText. I do in this way:

```
new TextFormField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
      counterText: "some text",
      labelText: header),
);
```

Everything is ok except the fact that I need to move counter text to the left but by the default, it is on the right side. How to change it? I know that there is `counterStyle` parameter but I have no idea how to use it to achieve moving text to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [`helperText`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InputDecoration/helperText.html) property what you are looking for.

Comment: Aww you're right! Thank you so much! I have additional question, do you know how to show this helper text only when text field has focus?

Comment: Yes sure I can try that! I guess it is better if you open another question because this is a whole different subject.